Unity child not rotating around parent?
So, I am working on a 2d brawler game, and I've just started combat, to manage combat I have created an empty that is a child of my character which I use as a hitbox to check if I've hit an enemy. I have tried a number of ways to get the empty to rotate around my character so that I can attack both to the left and to the right.
I've tried changing the characters x scale to -1 and I've tried rotating the character itself with transform.rotation, however none of it seems to work. It is my understanding that the child should rotate around and relative to the parent, but the best I have gotten is the empty's rotation changing, but the position won't change relative to the parent.
Here's the code I've been trying so far.
animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(moveHorizontal));
if (moveHorizontal > 0.1 || moveHorizontal < -0.1)
 {

spriteRenderer.flipX = rb2D.velocity.x > 0f;
rb2D.AddForce(new Vector2(moveHorizontal * playerSpeed, 0f) * Time.fixedDeltaTime, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
rb2D.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, moveHorizontal, 0f);

}

As this stands the player rotation switched between 1 and -1, I have also tried multiplying moveHorizontal by 180 but that also inverts my sprites in a way I haven't figured out how to fix and it still isn't rotating the empty correctly.
Here is a depiction of my problem


As you can see no matter which way the character is facing the empty is always to the left side. This is true if the characters rotation is alternating between positive and negative 180 as well.
Any ideas on how to get this to work in the way I'm thinking?

Still not sure how to fix this....
